flutter_shadcn has issues with BlocProvider
Im using shadcn_flutter in my flutter project, it uses multiple Cubits and I am using get_it to create the providers, my main.dart file looks like this:
main.dart
import 'features/main_injection_container.dart' as di;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.android,
  );
  await di.init();
  runApp(
    ShadcnApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorSchemes.darkNeutral(),
        radius: 0.5,
      ),
      home: const MainApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<UserCubit>(
          create: (context) => di.sl<UserCubit>(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<AuthCubit>(
          create: (context) => di.sl<AuthCubit>(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<CredentialsCubit>(
          create: (context) => di.sl<CredentialsCubit>(),
        ),
      ],
      child: const SignUp(),
    );
  }
}

and then when i try to do Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login())),  I get the following error:
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Login(state: _LoginState#12790):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<CredentialsCubit> above this BlocBuilder<CredentialsCubit, CredentialsState> Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that BlocBuilder<CredentialsCubit, CredentialsState> is under your MultiProvider/Provider<CredentialsCubit>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }

  consider using `builder` like so:

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter

The relevant error-causing widget was:
    Login Login:file:///Users/sami/Documents/flutter_projects/chacha_caller/lib/features/user/presentation/pages/login_signup/signup.dart:152:71

The same thing happens if I add the Login() page in the main.dart file and then Navigator.push() to the SignUp() page.
